# why does custom user causes the error django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren’t loaded yet.” in fresh project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I had a project all of a sudden I started seeing this error

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

i tried fixing it i failed miserably using all stack overflow i came across and django forum. So i started a new project, to see where I got it wrong, a very fresh project but as soon as i added in custom user model, the error wouldn't allow me even make migrations or migrate
note: this is the only file i have added besides adding in the settings:

```
"""
Database models
"""

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import(
    AbstractBaseUser,
    BaseUserManager,
    PermissionsMixin,
)
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils import timezone



class UserManager(BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin):
    """ minimum fields for all users"""
    def create_user(
            self,
            email,
            telephone,
            username,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            password=None,
            **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('You need to provide an email address')

        if not telephone:
            raise ValueError('You need to provide a telephone')

        if not username:
            raise ValueError('You need to set a username')

        """ calling the model this manager is responsible for with self.model."""
        user = self.model(
            email= self.normalize_email(email),
            telephone =telephone,
            username = username,
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(
            self,
            email,
            username,
            first_name,
            last_name,
            password,
            telephone,
            **extra_fields):
        """ calling the create_user method """
        user =self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            password=password,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            telephone=telephone,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using= self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """User in the system. """
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    families = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    """ required fields """
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    id_telephone_verified = models.IntegerField(default=False)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'telephone']
```

and the setting file is here

```
"""
Django settings for mascodlionheart project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-ep1+@q8hhpw%&r0mv1280xr5z2^w#1ro*-_%flx=z2jr_ydq(*'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'authapp',
    'coreapp'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mascodlionheart.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mascodlionheart.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authapp.User'



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

the full error:

```
(venv) Mbisas-MacBook-Pro:masco jc$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 416, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 116, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 269, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/authapp/models.py", line 20, in <module>
    class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 365, in __new__
    new_class._prepare()
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 411, in _prepare
    if not opts.managers:
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 453, in managers
    manager = copy.copy(manager)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 102, in copy
    return _reconstruct(x, None, *rv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/copy.py", line 263, in _reconstruct
    y = func(*args)
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 2524, in model_unpickle
    model = apps.get_model(*model_id)
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 201, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "/Users/jc/Desktop/masco/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 143, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```